# PHP: pretties of dynamic language. Design patterns

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have the following pattern. Or better the IDEA! 
There are "unit" classes inherited from `BaseUnit` and "users" classes inherited from `BaseUser`. Descendant  units and descendant  users are pretty similar in structure.

I want to apply a "toolbar" feature for users working with units

It can look like

```
class KickerUser extends BaseUser{
     public $toolbar = array('view()', 'kick("right_leg", "twice")')
}


class BaseUnit{
     public function view();

     public function kick($a, $b);

     public function bite($c);

     protected function applyToolbar($user){

     ///////////////HERE COMES THE TRICK////////
           foreach($user->toolbar as $t){
               $this->$t;
           }
     //  should I use eval() for this
     //  to become something like:  $this->bite('hard');
     //  i'm interested in making the readable code 
     //  and passing constant parameters
     /////////////HOW TO WRTITE THIS CORRECTLY ?
     }
}
```

Is this a good way of doing things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `eval` unless there isn't a better solution. In your case, it turns out there *is* a better solution -- [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and [`call_user_func_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php). The difference between the two functions is whether you pass the parameters directly or as an array.

For example, if you want to call `$this->kick('right_leg', 'twice')`, you could write it as:

```
call_user_func(array($this, 'kick'), 'right_leg', 'twice');
```

or:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, 'kick'), array('right_leg', 'twice'));
```

You can easily make this dynamic:

```
call_user_func_array(array($this, $methodName), $parametersArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

I was going to point you in the same direction that casablanca pointed you in, but he beat me to it :) .

Nevertheless, here's a little example you may find useful:

```
<?php
class MyClass{
    private $_name;

    public function __construct($name){
        $this->_name = $name;
    }

    private function sayMyName($asker){
        echo 'My name is ', $this->_name, ', ', $asker, '!';
    }

    public function askForName($asker){
        call_user_func(array($this, 'sayMyName'), $asker);
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass('Paul');
$obj->askForName('Mr. Rogers');
?>
```

Good luck,
Alin